# How can I get JSON response from Github Api?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at coding and I'm stuck. I'm trying to take JSON response from GitHub's REST API. I'm using external script file but it's not working. When I tried to use it in HTML with the script tag it's giving an error. I tried a way that is used for authenticating the token in fetch() it gives an error about that. It's called "header" I don't know about that. I will be happy if you guys help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GitHub API Trial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="github.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
getData();
const api_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos';
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(api_repo_url,
        {
            headers: {
                authorization: "TOKEN"
            }
        }
    )
    console.log(await response.json());
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer but you have a small typo, your url is called 'api_url' but then in the getData function it's called 'api_repo_url'. Maybe that will fix it, maybe it won't

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I will post it if I get the same error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and looks like the headers are unnecessary

```
getData();
async function getData() {
  const api_url = "https://api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos";
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  console.log(await response.json());
}
```

Comment: But authorization is required.

Comment: Why? When I access https://api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos it returns the result.

Comment: Oh,my bad authentication is not required for repos.

Comment: Do you know how can I only show only full name in console? I made const data = await response.json(); and at the end I wrote console.log(data.full_name) but It didn't work.

Comment: You can check https://api.github.com/users/alisirri .It has the "login" to the username and "name" (that not every user provide)

Answer (score 1):

Replace everything in the js file with this:

```
const api_repo_url = "https://api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos";
fetch(api_repo_url, {
    headers: {
        authorization: "TOKEN",
    },
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

No need for async either as .then() takes care of that

Comment: Do you know how can I only show only full name in console and how can I show it in HTML?

Comment: what do you mean by full name?

Comment: In JSON file there is full_name.

Comment: I need to take all items in JSON and use it in HTML

Comment: const api_repo_url = "api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos"; fetch(api_repo_url) .then((response) => response.json()) .then((data) => { data.forEach((repo) => { console.log(repo); }); }); That will go through each repo and console log it, if you end up wanting only the full name or something you can just say 'repo.full_name' or whatever it is. if you go into the console log you can see all the properties it gives you so you can just go through them and see which ones you want

Comment: That's cool, thanks!

Comment: I tried writing console.log(repo.name) but It's giving the all items in JSON again.

Comment: const api_repo_url = "https://api.github.com/users/alisirri/repos";
    fetch(api_repo_url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((repo) => {
                console.log(repo.name);
            });
        }); - this seems to do the trick. (p.s. make sure the api_repo_url has 'https://' before it as stack overflow takes it away)

Comment: It didn't work. Same thing happened again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/manninobobby/91sLpxya/3/ that's the jsfiddle I've just created, it seems to work in that

Comment: It worked! Thanks mate!